# Highlight menu using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have menu which is highlighted when a particular menu item is selected.
Now the problem comes when there are child items in the menu. I want to select the parent item and the child item of the menu.
Can anyone help me out.

Below is the html and javascript i use for highlighting the menu.

```
 <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MENU OPTIONS</li>

       <li><a onclick="getView(this,"menu","title");" title="First" menu="First" url="Folder/First" href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i><span>First Page</span></a></li>

       <li><a onclick="getView(this,"menu","title");" title="Second" menu="Second" url="Folder/Second" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span>Second Page</span></a></li>



      <li class="treeview active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span>Third Page</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>

<ul class="treeview-menu menu-open" style="display: block;">
    <li><a onclick="getView(this,"menu","title");" title="Child 1" menu="Child 1" url="Folder/Page" href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>First Child</a>
    </li>
    <li><a onclick="getView(this,"menu","title");" title="Child 2" menu="Child 2" url="Folder/Page" href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Second Child</a>
    </li>

    </ul></li>

        </ul>
```

The javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
if (localStorage.menu !== undefined) {
    $('.sidebar-menu>li').removeClass('selectedMenu');
    $(".sidebar-menu>li>a[menu='" + localStorage.menu + "']").parent().addClass('selectedMenu');
}
else {
    $(".sidebar-menu>li>a[menu='Home']").parent().addClass('selectedMenu');
}
```

Comment: can u create jsfiddle of ur code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.treeview-menu > li>a').click( function() { 
                $(this).closest("ul").siblings('a').addClass('selectMenu');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code when you use `parent()` you are referring to the parent `<li>`. Try using `parents()` with a class to query all the parents:

```
$(".sidebar-menu>li>a[menu='" + localStorage.menu + "']").parents('.treeview').addClass('selectedMenu');
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will hep you :-)

```css
ul,li, nav,a{margin:0;padding:0;}
a{text-decoration:none; font-family:helvetica; }


header h1{text-align:center;font-size:2em;border-bottom:5px solid #222; padding:.22em; font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #f62459;color:#fff;}
#vertical-menu{
  margin-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:10px;
  background:#f62459;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.main-menu {
 display:inline-block;
width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  
}
.main-menu li{
  position:relative;
  height:50px;
  box-shadow:0 -1px 0 0 #444, 0 -2px 0 0 #222;
}
.main-menu>li>a>i{
  color:#db0a5b;
  width:2em;
  height:100%;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:left; 
}
.main-menu>li:first-child, .submenu-1>li:first-child, .submenu-2>li:first-child, .submenu-3>li:first-child{
  box-shadow:none;
}
.main-menu>li:first-child>a, .submenu-1>li:first-child>a, .submenu-2>li:first-child>a, .submenu-3>li:first-child>a{
 border-top-left-radius:5px;
  border-top-right-radius:5px;
}
.main-menu>li:last-child>a, .submenu-1>li:last-child>a, .submenu-2>li:last-child>a, .submenu-3>li:last-child>a{
 border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}

.main-menu>li>a, .submenu-1>li>a, .submenu-2>li>a,.submenu-3>li>a{
  color:#d2527f;
  background:#2a2a2a;
  line-height:50px;
  display:block;
  padding:0 1em;
 
}

 .submenu-1,.submenu-2, .submenu-3{
  position:absolute;
  white-space:nowrap;
  top:-9999px;
}
.contain-submenu>a:first-child::after{
  content:" \f054";
  padding-left:1em;
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
}
/* revealing submenus */
.main-menu>li:hover .submenu-1, .submenu-1>li:hover .submenu-2, .submenu-2>li:hover .submenu-3{
  top:0;
   left:100%;
  transition: top .5s cubic-bezier(0.380,0.820,.790,.930);
  
}

.main-menu>li:hover>a{
  color:#22af70;
}
.submenu-1 li:hover>a{
  color:#22a7f0;
}
.submenu-2 li:hover>a{
  color:#f6db7f;
}
.submenu-3 li:hover>a{
  color:#f2784b;  
}

/* Author */
article{
  text-align:left;
  margin-left:20px;
  }
article p{
  font-size:1.2em;
  color:#f33039;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Creating vertical menu bar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <nav id="vertical-menu">
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Link Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="contain-submenu"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>Link Item 2 </a>
        <ul class="submenu-1">
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
          <li class="contain-submenu" ><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
             <ul class="submenu-2">
               <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2.1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2.2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2.3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2.4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2.5</a></li>
               
             </ul>
          
          
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>Link Item 3</a></li>
      <li class="contain-submenu"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Link Item 4</a>
         <ul class="submenu-1">
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a></li>
          <li class="contain-submenu"><a href="#">Submenu item 3</a>
           <ul class="submenu-2">
             <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.1</a></li>
             <li class="contain-submenu"><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2</a>
               <ul class="submenu-3">
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2.1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2.2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2.3</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2.4</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.2.5</a></li>
               </ul>
             
             </li>
             <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Submenu item 3.4</a></li>
           </ul>
           
           </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu item 5</a></li>
        </ul>      
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>Link Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Link Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$('.treeview-menu > li>a').click( function() { 
   $(this).find("ul").siblings('a').addClass('selectMenu');
 });
```

Explanation :
Onclick of the menu it will find the next ul which has anchor element and add CSS Class.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.